# How to safely handle user input placed in a href attribute?

Tags: html, django, xss

I capture a string from untrusted users that is supposed to contain a URL. How do I safely include it in a Django template like this?:

```
<a href="{url}">...</a>
```

Is the following list of precautions sufficient?

1. Check that it begins with `http://` or `https://`
2. Ensure the `href` attribute is contained in double quotes.
3. Rely on Django template autoescaping to escape double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a template tag and use that:

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
```

Look at the source it does a bit more than what you've mentioned.